# Skipping whitespace when adding chars to a list

Tags: java

I am trying to take a user entered word or phrase and put the characters in alphabetical order by putting them in a list and sorting the list. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortAlphabetically {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Character> alpha = new ArrayList<Character>();

    System.out.println("Enter a word or phrase");
    StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder(scanner.next());
    scanner.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isWhitespace(input.charAt(i))) {
            input.deleteCharAt(i);
        } else {
            alpha.add(input.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    alpha.sort(null);
    System.out.println("Input sorted alphabetically: " + alpha);
    }
}
```

However, the input seems to stop being entered into the list after a white space character. For example:

```
Enter a word or phrase
cba fed
Input sorted alphabetically: [a, b, c]
```

I tried to fix this with

```
  if (Character.isWhitespace(input.charAt(i))) {
        input.deleteCharAt(i);
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to have done anything

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ - "*One of the most frequent categories of bad questions I see on StackOverflow is: "I wrote this program and it doesn’t work.
[20 lines of code]. And… that’s it.*"

Comment: Given your code that is what you would expect to happen.  You both step over the character and you delete it meaning you skip forward two characters. I suggest you step through the code in your debugger to see why.

Comment: in short, it doesn't ask you to delete the space, nor should you, so don't and it will work.

Comment: If you have to *skip* over a hole in the ground do you fill it in/delete it first or do you just skip over it.

Comment: you can debug the code to see the problem if you add `System.out.println(input);` to see that the string you are getting back from the call to `scanner.next()` only returns "cba". `System.out.println()` of variables throughout your program can be a easy and useful way to see what your program is doing and why it's behaving the way it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanner.next()` reads a single token, so it stops at the first white space.
If you use `scanner.nextLine()`, it will read the entire line, including the space.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `scanner.nextLine()` to get the entire line with all the white-spaces.
 In addition, you have a better way to implement the solution in just one line using simple java library functions in `java.lang.String`. Why waste lines!

```
System.out.println("Answer"+input.replaceAll( " ", "" ).toCharArray().toList().sort());
```